# excel/vba - find fist and last occurrence of a particular value in a column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So if I have a column such as:

```
    A1
1   Apple
2   Apple
3   Apple
4   Oj
5   Oj
6   Oj
7   Oj
8   Pear
9   Pear
```

How could I return the values 1 & 3 for Apple, 4 & 7 for OJ, etc?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: well I don't have code per se, but I am trying to get an idea of what is possible. Right now, I am thinking to store the value of the first cell and its row# as variables, go down 1 cell and check if its the same value, continue through this through a loop until it is not the same value, and store the row# of the cell above.

Comment: @bsapaka : that's **exactly** how to begin doing it.  If you need faster performance, there are a few techniques that you can try, but those are really "optimization" issues rather than basic design.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412389/find-a-row-index-of-a-number-that-occurred-first) might help you.

Answer (score 6):

Formula-wise you can use `MATCH` functions, e.g. for first Apple position

`=MATCH("Apple",A1:A9,0)`

for last

`=MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(A1:A9="Apple"),0))`

or if the fruit are sorted as per your example (or merely grouped) you can get the last by adding the number of apples to the first -1

so with first MATCH function in C1 that would be

`=COUNTIF(A1:A9,"Apple")+C1-1`