# Display the First Last Instance Of an Item in A Given Quarter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

In my spreadsheet I have a line similar to the one below for each day of the year. I am trying to write a formula that will find the first and last instance of "work" in column B and display the number of weeks between those two dates.

If anyone could provide some suggestions it would be greatly appreciated, I have been fighting with this for the last few hours.

```
|Date|Work Status|Tasks|
|01-Jan-16 (Fri) | Work | 7 |
|02-Jan-16 (Sat) | Day Off | 0 |
|03-Jan-16 (Sun) | Day Off | 0 |
```

Comment: Make it easier on yourself and add some more columns derived from those dates.    Once you have that, it's easy with a pivot table.

Comment: It looks like you changed the question since last night. The pivot table idea from @duffymo seemed like a good idea to me.  Anyway this link might help with the question as it is now: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412389/find-a-row-index-of-a-number-that-occurred-first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412389/find-a-row-index-of-a-number-that-occurred-first)

Comment: My answer still stands: Add more columns to make it possible for Excel to have the values you need on hand.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column that adds up time whenever the task column has anything else than "work".

```
=IF(B2<>"Work",1,0)
```

Then for a given period you do a sumifs() over that column with the period you are interested in, or a pivotchart if you are more familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula 
    {=(DATEVALUE(MID(INDEX(A2:$A$15,MAX(("Work"=MID(A2:A15,20,4))*MATCH(ROW(A2:A15),ROW(A2:A15)))),2,9))-DATEVALUE(MID(INDEX(A2:$A$10,MATCH("*"&"Work"&"*",A2:$A$10,0)),2,9)))/7}

The first part returns the date associated with the last instance of "Work" in the list and the second part returns the first instance. There may be a way to simplify this a bit if you play around with the formula.

[image]